# Powershell filter contents to find file or directory

Tags: powershell

I'm reading in contents of a text file that includes files and folders that I'm applying audit settings to.  The folders have a few different settings on the SACL so I wanted to filter to find all the files and do an action and then do a different action to only the directories.  I'm having trouble finding a way to filter/differentiate between the two.  I'm using PowerShell v2.0, upgrading may not be a possibility.

Here's the code I have, I know it doesn't work, but gives an idea of my thinking:

```
import-module NTFSSecurity
$Targetfiles = Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt


if($Targetfiles -match ".exe or .dll or .msc"){
$files = $Targetfiles -match ".exe or .dll or .msc"
foreach ($File in $files){

    Get-NTFSAudit -Path $files | Remove-NTFSAudit -PassThru 
    Add-NTFSAudit -Path $files -Account 'NT Authority\Everyone' -AccessRights FullControl -Type    Failure -AppliesTo ThisFolderOnly
    Add-NTFSAudit -Path $files -Account 'NT Authority\Everyone' -AccessRights ExecuteFile,       AppendData, Delete, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership -Type Success -AppliesTo ThisFolderOnly
}
}    
else{

    $directories = $Targetfiles -notmatch ".exe or .dll or .msc"
    foreach ($Directory in $directories){
    Get-NTFSAudit -Path $directories | Remove-NTFSAudit -PassThru 
    Add-NTFSAudit -Path $directories -Account 'NT Authority\Everyone' -AccessRights FullControl -         Type Failure -AppliesTo ThisFolderOnly
    Add-NTFSAudit -Path $directories -Account 'NT Authority\Everyone' -AccessRights ExecuteFile, AppendData, ReadData,  CreateFiles, Delete, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership -Type Success -AppliesTo ThisFolderOnly
    }
}
```

Obviously the -match/-notmatch isn't working.  I want the script to check for all the items with an extension, put them into $files and then do the work and anything that doesn't have an extension, go into $directories and do that work.  I'm still learning, so my logic may not work.  I've tried "." with -match, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

The module can be found here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85#content

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with that particular module so I can't debug anything there, but for your logic this is what I'd use:

```
Import-Module NTFSSecurity;
Get-Content C:\Temp\test.txt | ForEach-Object {
    If (Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf) {
        If ((Get-Item $_).Extension -in ('.exe','.dll','.msc')) {
            #Apply executable file rule
        }
    } ElseIf (Test-Path $_ -PathType Container) {
        #Apply folder rule
    } Else {
        Write-Output "Path not found: $_";
    }
}
```

1. Import the module.
2. Get the content of the file
3. For each line of the content...
4. If it's a leaf object (aka, a file), check if it has the .exe, .dll, or .msc extension.  If so, apply the NTFSSecurity commands for files.
5. If it's a container (aka, a directory), apply the NTFSSecurity commands for directory.
6. If it wasn't a leaf or a container, it's because it wasn't a valid path at all.

My syntax is a bit pedantic and could be improved, but this should get you started.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish and this is the most straightforward version.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately, I believe the -in expression was introduced with PowerShell 3.0.  I'm on a tightly controlled network and upgrading isn't possible :(

Comment: @watcherseye You can bust it apart like `((Get-Item $_).Extension -eq '.exe') -or (Get-Item $_).Extension -eq '.dll') -or (Get-Item $_).Extension -eq '.msc'))`.  It's just less readable.